# How to modify Prestashop Carrier module front office?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am building a Prestashop Carrier module. I want to modify the front side of Carrier module, where the list of carriers are offered with different prices. I haven't found anything from the docs.

This is something I want to do:

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone guides me in the right direction.

Comment: What features do you want in your shipping module which you want to show on front end.?

Comment: @Nimish I need to add a description field. So that a user can add some instructions. Also I want to show some Note.

Comment: Just take a sampe carrier method and see how it is rendering data on shipping page. Write same code but add description field in that tpl and use forms so that you can trigger submit button on clicking checkout button and save description field.

Comment: @Nimish Can you please provide me some sample carrier code example which fulfills my requirement?